# How to Install TestNG in Latest Eclipse Version (2023-03)

Tags: eclipse, testng

when using Help --> Install New Software -->https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site

```
Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/compositeContent.xml.
Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/compositeContent.xml.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

When trying Eclipse Market Place:

```
Unable to read repository at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/compositeContent.xml.
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**

- Archive Installation:

** Downloaded from here https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot,

[image]
TestNG - jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/content.jar!/

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.beust.jcommander_1.78.0.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.beust.jcommander_1.78.0.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.beust.jcommander.source_1.78.0.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.beust.jcommander.source_1.78.0.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.google.guava_21.0.0.v20170206-1425.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/com.google.guava_21.0.0.v20170206-1425.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh_2.0.0.b6.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.apache-extras.beanshell.bsh.source_2.0.0.b6.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.testng_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.testng_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/features/org.testng.eclipse_7.4.0.202106051955.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/features/org.testng.eclipse_7.4.0.202106051955.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/features/org.testng.p2.feature_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/features/org.testng.p2.feature_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.testng.source_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.testng.source_7.4.0.r202105021533.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.webjars.jquery_3.5.1.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.webjars.jquery_3.5.1.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.webjars.jquery.source_3.5.1.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.webjars.jquery.source_3.5.1.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.yaml.snakeyaml_1.21.0.jar
Artifact not found: jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.yaml.snakeyaml.source_1.21.0.jar.
jar:file:/C:/Users/{user}/Downloads/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite/artifacts.jar!/plugins/org.yaml.snakeyaml.source_1.21.0.jar
```

- Offline Installation:

https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot

```
Downloaded from here and extracted..
```

Go to the eclipse installation directory and look for the “dropins” folder there.
Create a folder inside the dropins folder and name it as “testng-eclipse-7.4“.

Extract the “site_assembly.zip” file and copy its content i.e. the “features” and “plugins” folders to the newly created “testng-eclipse-7.4” directory.

```
The features folder contains the following two files.
org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar

The plugins folder contains these two files.
org.testng.eclipse.maven_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
org.testng.eclipse_6.11.0.201703011520.jar
```

Restarted the eclipse.. But still no TestNG is available..

Error log

```
eclipse.buildId=4.27.0.20230309-1200
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\{user}\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2023-06-01 09:02:42.039

org.eclipse.core.runtime
Error
Thu Jun 01 09:02:52 IST 2023
Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/org.testng.eclipse/icons/full/main16/testng_blur.gif

java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "org.testng.eclipse".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImagePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImagePathAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.LazyResourceManager.create(LazyResourceManager.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ResourceManager.createImageWithDefault(ResourceManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageRegistry.get(ImageRegistry.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImageFromURI(SWTPartRenderer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:677)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1083)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Comment: _Latest_ is not a proper version number. Please tell the exact version number. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` sounds like an outdated Java (better run Eclipse with the Java with which it is shipped).

Comment: C:\Users\{user}>java -version
java version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+9-LTS-191, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Please tell what I asked for: go to the Error Log view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: added that error log.. behind firewall

Comment: For option one and two you have correctly configure your proxy in the preferences _General > Network Connections_. Option three is unclear: which ZIP file did you downloaded and what did you then? Option four: on the mentioned website I see only zipped update sites, but nothing that can be put into the `dropins` folder, nor a description that says so. The error seems to come from option four.

Comment: For option 1 & 2 . .I have used Direct and Native both connections. no luck.. For option 3  i have downloaded testng files from https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot.

Comment: For option 1+2 you need to know your proxy settings. Option 3: on https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse#install-snapshot there are many downloads available. Make sure `dropins` is empty, choose an option, delete the error log, reproduce the error and show the first error from the error log. Also provide an exact step-by-step instruction on how to reproduce your issue (avoid vague phrases like "no luck").

Comment: For option 1+2 you need to know your proxy settings.. do i need to use proxy ?

Comment: This depends on your environment.

Comment: 1. I dont have proxy details.. 2.  I have download latest 7.4.0  3) dropins folder under eclipse installation directory is empty and i have creeated testng-eclipse-7.4 folder under that and relevant files which is in 7.4.0 jars dropped there

Comment: If the `features` folder contains JARs, then it is an update site which cannot be dropped into the `dropins` folder. _"I have download latest 7.4.0"_ - If you have downloaded something, don't keep people guessing (the string `latest 7.4.0` cannot be found on the mentioned site), just provide the download link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253911/discussion-between-changan-and-howlger).

Comment: Does it work when in _Help > Install New Software..._ you work with the downloaded zipped update site and the option _Contact all update sites during install to find required software_ disabled? Otherwise, tell the exact error.

Comment: I have tried checkbox enabled and disabled both for contact all update sites. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed This error is already given in the psost..

Comment: So you downloaded [this ZIP file](https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/zipped/7.4.0.202106051955/org.testng.eclipse.updatesite.zip). Then in Eclipse you went to _Help > Install New Software..._, clicked the _Add..._ button and then in the _Add Repository_ dialog clicked the _Archive..._ button and chose the downloaded ZIP file, right? Did you get the error already then or only later after selecting something? And if so, during the selection of what? To make clear, this all works for me and it's complete unclear to me which steps you took and when and which exact error you got.